# Import Firefox 3.x passwords into Firefox 4

Tags: passwords, import, firefox

How to import passwords from Firefox 3 to the new Firefox 4?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to export your Firefox 3.x passwords in the Security tab shown when you select the Tools | Options... menu item. I don't have Firefox 4 installed, but there should be a similar spot in its Options to import them.

**Update**

Sorry I didn't realize this wasn't core functionality. In order to export/import your passwords you'll need to install the [password-exporter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/password-exporter/) Firefox addon. It supports `Firefox 3.0 - 7.*`.

Comment: There is no export option that I can see in the security tab ...

Answer (score 2):

In case you were using **Firefox Sync** (formerly know as "Mozilla Sync") on 3.x, then your passwords will be synced automatically as soon as you log on to it.

Starting from Firefox 4.x, the Firefox Sync is a built in, including all the future versions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the old Firefox was at least version 3.5 and you did not set a master password you can simply copy the file `signons.sqlite` from your old profile to the new profile directory.